# Should I use properties for the properties of properties?

Tags: object-oriented, class, clean-code, properties

Sometimes I use some indirect properties to set or get some other sub-properties,

I give an example

```
class Page
{
    public string MainText 
    { set { MainParagraph.Text = value; } get { return MainParagraph.Text; }}
    public TextBlock MainParagraph {set; get;}
    public TextBlock FootNotes {set; get;}
}

class TextBlock
{        
    public String Text {set; get;}
    public bool   RightToLeft {set; get;}
}
```

Without the `MainText` property of the `Page` I have to use `myPage.MainParagraph.Text = something` and now I use `myPage.MainText = something`, however one may still use the first alternative. (Should I prevent it?)

Please note `Text` is not a real property of `Page` and in this way it may represent some sub-properties but not all of them. Is there any trade off?

For example for the `RightToLeft` property I prefer `myPage.FootNote.RightToLeft = true` because it's an specific attribute of each `TextBlock` but `MainText` could still be known as the main text of each page.

Is it better to make `FootNotes` public, but `MainParagraph` private? Then do I need to define a property in the `Page` for every property of the `MainParagraph`?

Comment: are you aware of [Law Of Demeter](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/211292/how-to-solve-train-wreck-properties-problem-that-violates-law-of-demeter)?

Comment: @gnat thank you, then not only it is more convenient but is recommended too!

Comment: No... Hiding a Law of Demeter violation behind a property call does not really fix the problem the Law aims to prevent.

Comment: @gnat My question is more specific with more details now, please reconsider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making "wrapper properties" like this is fine if it's the cleanest way to implement the API that you want this class to have.

However, the specific example you posted does look questionable to me, mostly because the user of your class can now do exactly the same thing in two different ways: `myPage.MainParagraph.Text` and `myPage.MainText`. Since the user doesn't (and shouldn't) know that one simply wraps the other, this raises all sorts of questions he shouldn't have to ask. Yes, documentation can help, but in my opinion the confusion and complication added by this duplicate outweighs the convenience of not having to type those extra two characters.

What you probably want to do is completely hide the TextBlock object, and provide wrappers for only those properties that you want the Page user to have access to. Then if you later decide TextBlock is not the best implementation of Page, it's much easier to change things. Alternatively, you can leave the TextBlock completely exposed with no wrappers, if you think that telling the user "this is how you get the TextBlock object that Page uses" is a better choice for your API.

**Edit:** Now that you've updated the question, and I can see that your Page class contains *two* TextBlock objects, I would lean very strongly towards making the two TextBlocks public and having no wrappers. Any attempt to wrap them immediately leads to potential confusion with disambiguating the MainParagraph wrapper from the Footer wrapper from the Header wrapper you'll probably add in version 3.0 from any of the actual TextBlock properties they're all implemented with. It's so much simpler to just expose both and let the TextBlock API do its job.

Comment: I changed the example to say my real problem, please consider it.

Comment: Hm, I think my answer and @DixonD's are still valid; we just need to change the class names.  But now I can say that making the TextBlocks public and having no wrappers would be the far more intuitive option.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you should either expose object `TextBlock` from `Page` or have delegate methods in `Page` to provide access to the methods of `TextBlock` but not both. I guess it depends how many properties and methods of `TextBlock` you want to expose, so if they are many, that just provide `TextBlock` and do not have all those simple delegations.

You can also check two opposite refactorings from the Fowler's catalog: [Hide Delegate](http://refactoring.com/catalog/hideDelegate.html) and [Remove Middle Man](http://refactoring.com/catalog/removeMiddleMan.html)